# Issues with most basic e4x test

Tags: javascript, firefox, e4x

When I load a page containing e4x in FF 3.5, I get no inkling that e4x even exists in the browser's JS implementation. Notes below, but here's my HTML :

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>e4x test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/dojo/dojo/dojo.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript;e4x=1">
        function hello() {
            var x = new XML();
            x = <foo></foo>
            dojo.byId("container").innerHTML = "Print me!" + x.toXMLString();
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.addOnLoad(hello);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I inspect in firebug, it says x doesn't have a toString() method, and my IDE (aptana) thinks that XML is not an object type.  Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that it was working all along, but your browser doesn't recognize a "foo" tag and because it does not know how to render it, it ignores it.  By putting something inside of your foo tag you would get content out.

BTW: The new XML() statement is entirely unnecessary.  You can just do this:

```
var x = <foo>bar</foo>;
```

That will create a new XML object for you.  Saying new XML() is like saying new String().  You can do it, but it is just a waste of space.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need more in the XML for it to print anything out.  bar works, for example.  I'm not sure why, but that is what fixed it!